# Error in copying records

Tags: mysql

I have a parent table, and child. The child is newly created table. I connected the child with the parent using foreign key.

The parent already contains data. The child is new empty one. I need to copy data from previous child table (that was previously connected to the parent but I removed the connection because of duplications in values in a column that is supposed to be unique (note: this column that I discovered that it should be unique is not the foreign key of course). However, I type the following statement in order to copy records from the previous child that was connected to the parent:

```
insert into databasename.newchild select distinct * from databasename.previouschild group by uniquename;
```

The difference between the new child & the old one, is that I specified a column as unique while it was not unique in the previous child which cause duplicates that shoud not be.

Mysql gives me error:

Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databsename`.`newchildtable`, CONSTRAINT `newchildforeignkeyname` FOREIGN KEY (`newchildforeignkeyname`) REFERENCES `parenttable` (`parentuniquecolumn`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE)

What could be the problem ?

Comment: The error message simply implies that your query works fine but you're violating the *foreign key constraint*.

Comment: since the old child was already connected to the parent, this ensures that no record in the child does not exists in the parent. I don't know what else can I check ?